# I want to display the value of a variable using innerHTML but my code isnt working

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I tried displaying the value of a variable on clicking a button with the following code. But it isn't working.

```
var i = document.getElementById("inp").value;
var m=i-1;
var s=59;
function func() 
{
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = m +":"+s;
}
```

Comment: did you called `func`?

Comment: What is the error? did you try writing to console log or alerts to understand whats happeneing? can you attach the relevant html code as well?

Comment: yes I called func() through html . Here's the code <input id="inp" type="text" name="min">Set min</input>
    <div id="display">00:00</div>
    <div id="btns">
        <a href="#" class="button" onclick="setTimeout(func,1000)">Start</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Stop</a>

    </div>

Comment: please open your browser console and check whether you get any error or not.

Answer (score 3):

In order to apply your code inside the function, you must run (call) the function:

```
var i = document.getElementById("inp").value;
var m=i-1;
var s=59;

function func() 
{
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = m +":"+s;
}

func();
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw4tt8qr/) for a live example.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your Javascript is executed the element with your id is not yet loaded because your script is located in the head.

Make sure the element you are trying to access actually exists at that moment.
Append the `<script>`-section at the end of your body and dont include it in the `<head>`.
That way the javascript runs when every element is already loaded.

Comment: I've upvoted this because this is one of the possible reasons for such behavior, but I think that @Verhaeren answer is the solution.

Comment: According to the comment on his own post @xyz is already calling the function so that might not be the problem here

Comment: The comment where the OP states that the function is being called wasn't there when I posted. This is what is added now according with that comment (this answer could be the solution thus): http://jsfiddle.net/7n1faoL6/